# Django model property without a field

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to set a property in django (for backwards compatibility), without a corresponding field? Here is a simple test case with a custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  ...
  permissions = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  @property
  def is_staff(self):
    return self.permissions >= 2
  @is_staff.setter
  def is_staff(self, value):
    if value and not self.is_staff:
      self.permissions = 2
    if not value and self.is_staff:
      self.permissions = 1
```

Now when I try to load this user using the default admin interface, I get the following error: `'CustomUserAdmin.list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_staff' which does not refer to a Field.`

Is there a way to set this up so that the model provides `is_staff` as a function of another field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly possible, and the code you've given would not by itself cause any problems. The problem only comes because you've tried to use that property in the admin `list_filter`, which you can't do, because like any filtering that translates into a db query, so needs an actual db field.

Comment: OK, thought something like that would be the case. In this example it might be easier to edit the admin, but is there a workaround I could use to provide `is_staff` so that changes to `is_staff` and `permissions` set both fields correctly?